# strip() on multiple column not working - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a generic dataframe cleansing function as follows

```
def cleanse_data(df,cols_to_strip):
    df.replace({'(?=.*)(\s*\[.*\]\s*)':'','\*':'','\+':'',',.*':'','—':''},inplace=True, regex=True)
    df.columns.str.strip()
    df[cols_to_strip] = df[cols_to_strip].applymap(lambda x: x.strip())
    return df
```

the second argument takes the list of columns in the dataframe to stip() (i.e. remove its whitespaces) .... calling this function

```
nhl_df = cleanse_data(nhl_df,['team'])
print(nhl_df[nhl_df['team']=='Jose Sharks']) #doesnt work
print(nhl_df[nhl_df['team'].str.strip()=='Jose Sharks']) #works
```

so it seems that for some reason the stripping inside the cleansing function didnt work (though the regex replacement worked fine !!) ... any reason for this ??

Comment: It should working, if change `df[cols_to_strip] = df[cols_to_strip].applymap(lambda x: x.strip())` to `df[cols_to_strip] = df[cols_to_strip].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())` still `print(nhl_df[nhl_df['team']=='Jose Sharks'])` not working?

Comment: still not working yes @jezrael

Comment: If check `EDIT` in my answer, what return `print(nhl_df.loc[nhl_df['team'].str.contains('Jose Sharks'), 'team'].tolist()) ` ?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), but your solution should working well:

```
df[cols_to_strip] = df[cols_to_strip].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
```

EDIT: Is possible test ouput of your function?

```
nhl_df = cleanse_data(nhl_df,['team'])
print(nhl_df.loc[nhl_df['team'].str.contains('Jose Sharks'), 'team'].tolist())
```